# How to extend NSTextStorage?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextstorage

According to documentation, I try to subclass NSTextStorage and use it in text view:

```
/*
 NSTextStorage is a semi-abstract subclass of NSMutableAttributedString. It
 implements change management (beginEditing/endEditing), verification of
 attributes, delegate handling, and layout management notification. The one
 aspect it does not implement is the actual attributed string storage --- this is
 left up to the subclassers, which need to override the two
 NSMutableAttributedString primitives:

 - (void)replaceCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range withString:(NSString *)str;
 - (void)setAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attrs range:(NSRange)range;

*/
```

So I try to use delegate, to handle all needed events with same functionality:

```
@implementation MyTextStorage

- (id) init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self != nil) {
        storage = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc {
    [storage release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (NSString *) string {
    return [storage string];
}

- (void) replaceCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range withString:(NSString *)str {
    [storage replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:str];
}

- (void)setAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attrs range:(NSRange)range {
    [storage setAttributes:attrs range:range];
}


@end
```

It is no matter what I'm use as delegate: NSTextStorage or NSMutableAttributedString, The result is the same:

> An uncaught exception was raised
>   *** NSRunStorage, _NSBlockNumberForIndex(): index (18446744073709551615) beyond array
>   bounds (0)
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
>   '*** NSRunStorage,
>   _NSBlockNumberForIndex(): index (18446744073709551615) beyond array
>   bounds (0)'

Stack trace:

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff840cd7b4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff885390f3 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff840cd5d7 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 103
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff840cd564 +[NSException raise:format:] + 148
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff86cc6288 _NSBlockNumberForIndex + 86
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff86cc71d5 -[NSLayoutManager textContainerForGlyphAtIndex:effectiveRange:] + 364
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff86d1f121 -[NSTextView(NSSharing) didChangeText] + 340
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff86d44b68 -[NSTextView insertText:replacementRange:] + 2763
    8   CocoaCalculator                     0x0000000100002312 -[CalcTextView insertText:] + 65
    9   CocoaCalculator                     0x00000001000027ac -[CalcTextContainer initWithFrame:] + 1176
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff86c23d44 -[NSCustomView nibInstantiate] + 646
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff86b7be17 -[NSIBObjectData instantiateObject:] + 259
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff86b7b202 -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] + 336
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff86b7988d loadNib + 226
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff86b78d9a +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:]
```

Termination start when I try to call

```
[textView insertText:@"123"];
```

But in standard NSTextStorage version all works properly.

What I need to do to extend this class ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In addition to the NSAttributedString primitive methods that need implemented, I believe you also need to make a call to `edited:range:changeInLength:` inside your overrides of `replaceCharactersInRange:withString:` and `setAttributes:range:` respectively.

Something like:

```
- (void) replaceCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range withString:(NSString *)str {
    [storage replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:str];
    [self edited:NSTextStorageEditedCharacters range:range changeInLength:[str length] - range.length];
}

- (void)setAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attrs range:(NSRange)range {
    [storage setAttributes:attrs range:range];
    [self edited:NSTextStorageEditedAttributes range:range changeInLength:0];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `NSTextStorage` documentation is a little bit vague in this area. The comment you quote in your question, about only needing to override 2 of the `NSMutableAttributedString` primitives only means that you don't have to override the other `NSMutableAttributedString` primitives.

You still have to override the primitives for the `NSAttributedString` superclass. Which means you need to implement `-attributesAtIndex:effectiveRange:`, `-length` and `-string`. I notice you did include an implementation of `-string`, so the two remaining ought to do it.

If you add:

```
- (NSUInteger)length
{
     return [storage length];
}

- (NSDictionary *)attributesAtIndex:(NSUInteger)location effectiveRange:(NSRangePointer)range
{
      return [storage attributesAtIndex:location effectiveRange:range];
}
```

... then hopefully it will fix this problem.

Comment: According to the [current docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextStorageLayer/Tasks/Subclassing.html) `length` is not a primitive and does not need to be implemented by subclasses.  You are correct regarding `attributesAtIndex:effectiveRange:` and `string`, though.