# Range-related exception when subclassing NSTextStorage on Mavericks

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-mavericks, nstextview, nstextstorage

My application uses my own subclass of `NSTextStorage` and everything worked fine until Mavericks. Even with the most stripped-down version, I get an exception as soon I init a text view with it. I read the documentation and also looked at [How to extend NSTextStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960550/how-to-extend-nstextstorage). Hopefully one of you knows if Apple changed something or if I'm doing something wrong.

Info you probably need to help me:

**the exception:**

> TextViewCheck[12542:303] : Exception *** 
>   NSRunStorage (0x6000000a4200), _replaceElements(): replaced range {0, 929} extends 
>   beyond current run storage size 928. raised during typesetting layout manager 
>   *NSLayoutManager: 0x100106a80* 
>   1 containers, text backing has 928 characters
>   selected character range {0, 0} affinity: upstream granularity: character
>   marked character range {0, 0}
>   Currently holding 928 glyphs. 
>   Glyph tree contents:  928 characters, 928 glyphs, 1 nodes, 64 node bytes, 960
>   storage bytes, 1024 total bytes, 1.10 bytes per character, 1.10 bytes per glyph
>   Layout tree contents:  928 characters, 928 glyphs, 0 laid glyphs, 0 laid line
>   fragments, 1 nodes, 64 node bytes, 0 storage bytes, 64 total bytes, 0.07 bytes 
>   per character, 0.07 bytes per glyph, 0.00 laid glyphs per laid line fragment, 
>   0.00 bytes per laid line fragment
>   , glyph range {0 928}. Ignoring...

**the backtrace**

```
thread #1: tid = 0x137013, 0x00007fff8ad7e44e AppKit`_NSGlyphTreeGetGlyphsInRange + 1179, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1002c0000)

frame #0: 0x00007fff8ad7e44e AppKit`_NSGlyphTreeGetGlyphsInRange + 1179
frame #1: 0x00007fff8ad7dfa1 AppKit`-[NSLayoutManager getGlyphsInRange:glyphs:characterIndexes:glyphInscriptions:elasticBits:bidiLevels:] + 92
frame #2: 0x00007fff8ad4d8b6 AppKit`-[NSATSGlyphStorage setGlyphRange:characterRange:] + 3724
frame #3: 0x00007fff8ad4c8be AppKit`-[NSATSTypesetter _ctTypesetter] + 306
frame #4: 0x00007fff8ad4baf9 AppKit`-[NSATSLineFragment layoutForStartingGlyphAtIndex:characterIndex:minPosition:maxPosition:lineFragmentRect:] + 85
frame #5: 0x00007fff8ad4a64e AppKit`-[NSATSTypesetter _layoutLineFragmentStartingWithGlyphAtIndex:characterIndex:atPoint:renderingContext:] + 2777
frame #6: 0x00007fff8ad7dc79 AppKit`-[NSATSTypesetter layoutParagraphAtPoint:] + 149
frame #7: 0x00007fff8b3f5b45 AppKit`-[NSTypesetter _layoutGlyphsInLayoutManager:startingAtGlyphIndex:maxNumberOfLineFragments:maxCharacterIndex:nextGlyphIndex:nextCharacterIndex:] + 4043
frame #8: 0x00007fff8ad7cc9d AppKit`-[NSTypesetter layoutCharactersInRange:forLayoutManager:maximumNumberOfLineFragments:] + 202
frame #9: 0x00007fff8ad7cb81 AppKit`-[NSATSTypesetter layoutCharactersInRange:forLayoutManager:maximumNumberOfLineFragments:] + 1107
frame #10: 0x00007fff8ad7b219 AppKit`-[NSLayoutManager(NSPrivate) _fillLayoutHoleForCharacterRange:desiredNumberOfLines:isSoft:] + 1306
frame #11: 0x00007fff8ae24ad9 AppKit`_NSFastFillAllLayoutHolesForGlyphRange + 1435
frame #12: 0x00007fff8ae6ddbd AppKit`-[NSLayoutManager(NSPrivate) _firstPassGlyphRangeForBoundingRect:inTextContainer:okToFillHoles:] + 309
frame #13: 0x00007fff8ae6cea4 AppKit`-[NSLayoutManager(NSPrivate) _glyphRangeForBoundingRect:inTextContainer:fast:okToFillHoles:] + 875
frame #14: 0x00007fff8add81b2 AppKit`-[NSTextView setNeedsDisplayInRect:avoidAdditionalLayout:] + 1466
frame #15: 0x00007fff8acb4222 AppKit`-[NSView setNeedsDisplay:] + 81
frame #16: 0x00007fff8add68d9 AppKit`-[NSTextView setTextContainer:] + 699
frame #17: 0x00007fff8add651a AppKit`-[NSTextContainer setTextView:] + 263
...
```

**the code:**

*TTTSimpleTextStorage.m*

```
@implementation TTTSimpleTextStorage

- (id)initWithAttributedString:(NSAttributedString *)attrStr {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        contents = attrStr ? [attrStr mutableCopy] :
        [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}


- init {
    return [self initWithAttributedString:nil];
}

- (NSString *)string {
    return [contents string];
}

- (NSDictionary *)attributesAtIndex:(NSUInteger)location
                 effectiveRange:(NSRange *)range {
    return [contents attributesAtIndex:location effectiveRange:range];
}

- (void)replaceCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range withString:(NSString
                                                        *)str {
    NSInteger origLen = [self length];
    [contents replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:str];
    [self edited:NSTextStorageEditedCharacters range:range
          changeInLength:[self length] - origLen];
}

- (void)setAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attrs range:(NSRange)range {
    [contents setAttributes:attrs range:range];
    [self edited:NSTextStorageEditedCharacters range:range
       changeInLength:0];
}

@end
```

**How I use it**

This is in the MainWindowController - awakeFromNib, the window IBOutlet has a NSView as subview named *container* and a random string *string1*

```
nts1 = [[TTTSimpleTextStorage alloc] initWithString:string1];

NSLayoutManager* lm1 = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];
[nts1 addLayoutManager:lm1];

NSTextContainer* tc1 = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithContainerSize:NSMakeSize(400, 280)];
[lm1 addTextContainer:tc1];


tv1 = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(40, 20, 400, 280) textContainer:tc1];  // here it crashes

[self.container addSubview:tv1];
[self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
[self.window makeFirstResponder:tv1];
```

Comment: It looks like an off-by-one error in one of your ranges.

Comment: @BradAllred: right, but I don't know where I create that error or how I can solve it. apparently the string I use has 928 characters and until that crash only the methods -(id)init..., -(NSString*)string and -(NSDictionary*)attributesAtIndex... get called. and in the attributesAtIndex the range is (928,0)

Comment: comment out all your overrides except the first and run it. if it doesn't crash add the next method and repeat till you find the culprit. my money is on `replaceCharactersInRange`

Comment: thanks for your answers. I experimented a bit but all those methods have to be overwritten not only according to the documentation, it doesn't compile without them at all. I tried to return different stuff (like manipulating the returned range, checking indices for running over) but I discovered that `replaceCharactersInRange` doesn't get called. only `string` and `attributesAtIndex`.

Answer (score 0):

In replaceCharactersInRange, you are setting origLen to [self length], and one line later you're calculating the changeInLength by subtracting origLen with [self length], which is effectively:

```
NSInteger origLen = self.length;
// ...
changeInLength: origLen - self.length
```

I think you rather want:

```
changeInLength: self.length - str.length];
```

Comment: Hey, I tried it out but it doesn't help. Meanwhile I wrote the Apple support and they think it is a bug somewhere in the Framework. I will report a bug in their bug tracker. My workaround is to not replace the `TextStorage` but to replace the `String` of it.